# Linear regression with multiple different outcomes (naming contains numbers) in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, linear-regression

I have a large dataset and want to build linear regression for >500 outcomes. The issue I am facing: outcomes have numbers within their names. Reproducible example:

```
id <- c('subject-1','subject-2', 'subject-3', 'subject-4')
color<-c('blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red')
sex<-c('M', 'M', 'F', 'M')
outcome-1<-(11, 4, 15,4)
outcome-2<-(63, 73, 23,23)
outcome-3<-c(14, 34, 35,3)
outcome-4<-c(8, 40, 45,30)
df <- data.frame(id, color, sex, outcome-1, outcome-2, outcome-3, outcome-4)
```

The desired output would be to have a table with following columns: my outcomes, Beta, SE, Pval and N (size). If there is someone expert that could help to do this wile using lapply or map, it would be great.

Comment: Hi, you might have a look at the `fixest` package and its advanced syntax that allows for multiple outcome variables (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669133/feols-fixest-loop-over-dependent-variable)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mishap with reproducible data example... Thanks for pointing it out. The problem is with naming of the outcomes (have both mixed character and number- eg. miRNA-195-a)

Comment: You don't define well what exactly you want to do. Until you do that, you won't get any useful answers. Do you want to fit separate linear regression models, one for each outcome variable?

Comment: Yes Roland, as I wrote in the ending of my question.
Table with following columns: my outcomes (one by one), Beta, SE, Pval and N (size)-  per each outcome- so each linear regression. Hope that is clear enough.

Comment: Reshape your data to long format and use `nlme::lmList`.